# Check if full text field has a date in a range

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Hello I am new to elastic world and I am trying to figure out how can I find if a field for example "text" (which represents the whole text indexed) has a date that is in a specific range ?

Example:
In doc_1 in field "text" we have "I was born on 27/05/1995" and I want to check if this document has a date inside it, which is between 20/05/1995 and 30/05/1995.

If this is not possible then how can I take this date "27/05/1995" and store it into a new field when I am indexing this doc ? And can you give me a tip about the best approach when we talk about indexing documents containing dates ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have multiple options here. To search for documents that are inside your date range you have to parse the dates from the texts and index them as date field in elasticsearch. You can either do that inside you application before you send the document to elasticsearch or you have a look at ingest nodes. Ingest nodes give you the opportunity to preprocess documents before indexing. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

As soon as you have documents in elasticsearch with a separate date field you can use a Range query to search: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: Thank you. I used ingest pipelines, grok processor and date processor to achieve this. But I got into another issue, how can I use a known grok pattern for an unknown number of times in the same message or how can I use a custom pattern to accomplish this? I tried to use a regex with a global flag but that flag is not recognized because when I write /g flag my regex is considerd wrong by ES. I checked the regex online and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using regular expression below to match certain dates in a text. date format I am looking for is "yyyy-mm-dd", you can shuffle span_multi inside clauses, to look for format you need. You can read about span [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html)

Mapping

```
PUT testindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content":{
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "a3PLFW0BY3127H1HVxyC",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "I was born on 2019/09/01"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bXPLFW0BY3127H1HaBwp",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "I was born on 2019/09/15"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "w3PLFW0BY3127H1HeBzg",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "I was born on 2019/09/20"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
GET testindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
----> clauses below look for year,month,date, you can change their order for desired
---->format
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "regexp": {
                "content": "(19|20)[0-9]{2}"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "regexp": {
                "content": "0[1-9]|1[012]"
              }
            }
          }
        },
         {
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "regexp": {
                "content": "1[5-9]|[2][0]"  --> regex for date from 15-20
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop": 0,
      "in_order": true
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bXPLFW0BY3127H1HaBwp",
        "_score" : 3.2095504,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "I was born on 2019/09/15"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "w3PLFW0BY3127H1HeBzg",
        "_score" : 3.2095504,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "I was born on 2019/09/20"
        }
      }
    ]
```