# In Elasticsearch, can I index date strings embedded in a document as a date type?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing documents with many embedded date strings of the format `"<month> <day>, <year>"`. Is it possible in Elasticsearch to recognize these strings as date types during the indexing process such that I can later query the documents using date ranges in the query, for example:

> find all documents that have *any* embedded date >= 2021-01-01 and the phrase "held on" within 5 words of the date

The problem is that the number of embedded dates within a document varies greatly (some documents have tens of dates, while others may have hundreds), so I don't see a way to extract them into separate, predefined fields.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841445/check-if-full-text-field-has-a-date-in-a-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only if you extract and map these into their own timestamp field, Elasticsearch won't natively pull that out

you could do that with an ingest pipeline for eg, using [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html) or [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dissect-processor.html) and then using [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-processor.html) on the extracted field

you could also use a [runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/runtime.html), but that's a little more complex, and the above option is more efficient in the long run

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I didn't expect I could do this in the general case (for _any_ date) but I'm going to experiment with both grok and [pattern replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html) to put dates in a format where I can do more specific queries.